# keep having permission error while creating a hdf5 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

I have the following segment of code to create a hdf5 file, and have used "with" statement to ensure the file is correctly closed. However, I still keep having the error message as follows.

```
   filename = 'E30.hdf5'
   try:
        with h5py.File(filename, 'w-') as f:
            print('---')
    except: 
        os.remove(filename)
        f = h5py.File(filename, 'w-')
```

However, I still keep having the error message as follows. In the working directory, there may already have an existing file with the name of 'E30.hdf5'. But does it really matter? I tried to delete it from windows directly. However, the windows does not allow me to delete it saying it is being opened.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e8ccfbc1b5d2> in vid_to_hdf(En, start, end, chunk)
      9     try:
---> 10         with h5py.File(filename, 'w-') as f:
     11             print('---')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fastai-py37\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, track_order, **kwds)
    407                                fapl, fcpl=make_fcpl(track_order=track_order),
--> 408                                swmr=swmr)
    409 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\fastai-py37\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    176     elif mode in ['w-', 'x']:
--> 177         fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
    178     elif mode == 'w':

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create()

OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'E30.hdf5', errno = 17, error message = 'File exists', flags = 15, o_flags = 502)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

<ipython-input-6-e8ccfbc1b5d2> in vid_to_hdf(En, start, end, chunk)
     11             print('---')
     12     except:
---> 13         os.remove(filename)
     14         f = h5py.File(filename, 'w-')
     15     # Create dataset within file

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'E30.hdf5'
```

Comment: It is not letting you remove the file to try again because another process is using it (maybe another python session). It seems that this is a "feature" of Windows. You will need to find the other process and stop it, and then hopefully it should work.

Comment: The race condition occurs when one thread tries to modify a shared resource at the same time that another thread is modifying that resource, threads need to be synchronized. You can utilize threading module acquire() and release() methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into multiple issues at once.
First, let's start with the `h5py.File()` access_mode flag.

- **w-** : Create file, fail if exists (avoids accidentally overwriting an existing file)
- **w** : Create file, truncate if exists (means it overwrites an existing file)
- **r+** : Read/write, file must exist (use to open an existing file to write data).

In your logic below, your `try:/except:` pattern will execute the `try:` statement if `E30.hdf5` **does not exist**. It will execute the `except:` statement if `E30.hdf5` **exists**.

This is complicated by different `h5py.File()` methods is each branch. Your `try:` branch uses the `with h5py.File() as f:` method. So, when your code executes this logic, the file will close cleanly at the end (without a `f.close()` statement).

HOWEVER, your `except:` branch uses `f=h5py.File()`. So, when your code executes this logic, you need a `f.close()` statement to ensure closure at the end.

This is the scenario I think you are experiencing:

1. I assume `E30.hdf5` does not exist the first time you run your code.
2. So, the first time you run, you go through the `try:` branch and the file is closed cleanly at the end.
3. The next time you run the code, `E30.hdf5` exists, so, you go through the `except:` branch. As a result, the file is NOT closed at the end of the process, and another process cannot access it (Python or the OS).

Coding suggestions:

Your `except:` block has the same behavior `mode=w`. The code below  behaves the same, and will always close the file when the process completes. Also, it is more readable (IMHO). Note: both methods delete `E30.hdf5` if it exists.

```
filename = 'E30.hdf5'
with h5py.File(filename, 'w') as f: # use mode=w
     print('---')
```

Make this change if there is a burning need to keep the `try:/except:` pattern: (it's useful to use `try:/except:` for access modes `w-` and `r+` WITHOUT the `os.remove(filename)`.)

```
filename = 'E30.hdf5'
try:
    with h5py.File(filename, 'w-') as f:
        print('---')
except: 
    os.remove(filename)
    with h5py.File(filename, 'w-') as f:
         print('+++')
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation.